# Can't update state passed down to each image individually

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I'm just starting out in React. I have two components that share/update the same state and therefore lifted the state to the parent component. This state is basically to show a loading animation while the image loads but when one image loads, the animation stops for the other images even though they haven't loaded. I would have set the loading state directly in the Image component but I want to reset the state through buttons present in another component. This is what my code looks like (I'm only showing the main parts of the code I need help with)

App Component

```
const changeSrcUrl = (e) => {
        e.target.id === "robot" ? setRobotType("?200x200") 
            : e.target.id === "kittens" ? setRobotType("?set=set4") 
            : e.target.id === "monster" ? setRobotType("?set=set2")
            : e.target.id === "avatar" ? setRobotType("?set=set5")  
            : setRobotType("?set=set3")    
        }


    const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(null)
    const onImageLoaded = (e) => {
      setLoaded(true)
    };

    const resetImgState = () => {
      setLoaded(false)  
    }
    return (
            <div className="tc">
                <h1 className="f1">Fola's RoboFriends</h1>
                <SearchBox searchChange={onSearchChange}/>
                <ButtonList  onClick={(e) => {
                    resetImgState()
                    changeSrcUrl(e)
                }}/>
                <Scroll>
                    <CardList loadState={loaded} load={onImageLoaded} changeType={type} robots={filteredRobots} />
                </Scroll>
            </div>
```

CardList component

```
const CardList = ({ robots, changeType, load, loadState }) => {
    return (
        <>
            {
                robots.map((user, i) => {
                    return  (
                        <Card 
                            key={i} 
                            id={robots[i].id} 
                            name={robots[i].name} 
                            email={robots[i].email} 
                            img={changeType}
                            load={load}
                            loadState={loadState}
                            keys={i}
                        />
                    )
                })
            }
        </>
    );
}
```

Card component

```
const Card = ({ name, email, id, img, loadState, load, keys}) => {
    return (
        <div className="tc hover-bg-light-purple bg-light-blue dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5 ">  
           <Image id={id} img={img} load={load} loadState={loadState} keys={keys} />
            <div>
                <h2>{name}</h2>
                <p>{email}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Image component

```
const Image = ({id, img, loadState, load, keys}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <img 
            alt=""
            src={`https://robohash.org/blteuwoqqqe${id}${img}`} 
            onLoad={load}
            id={id}
            />
            { !loadState && <div className="bg-light-blue container-overlay">
                <div className="tc" id="loading"></div>
            </div>} 
        </>
    )
}

export default Image;
```

```
ButtonList component
import Button from "./Button";

const ButtonList = ({ onClick}) => {
    return (
        <div className="button_list flex flex-wrap justify-center w-80 mw8">
            <Button id="robot" onClick={onClick} value={'Robots'}/>
            <Button id="monster" onClick={onClick} value={'Monsters'}/>
            <Button id="disembodied" onClick={onClick} value={'Disembodied'}/>
            <Button id="kittens" onClick={onClick} value={'Kittens'}/>
            <Button id="avatar" onClick={onClick} value={'Avatars'}/>
            <Button id="random" onClick={onClick} value={'Random'}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I've tried other solutions I've seen online but couldn't get them to work or at least work properly, tried getting the image id on load and comparing it against the id but the state for all images keep end up having the same id. I also tried creating an array of false values and assigning to each card component while mapping but I ran into problems while updating the states on image load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your state has been lifted to the parent, you are only maintaining a single Boolean (`loaded`) shared between all of your children. If one child sets it to true, it will be the source of truth for all children.

You will need to maintain your state as some sort of collection. For instance an array of `id`s of the loaded children.

You can read more on handling arrays as state in [the react docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state)

**[Update]: a few examples**

```
// loaded is an array of ids of loaded images
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState([])
// Whenever an image is loaded, add the id to the array.
const onImageLoaded = (id) => {
  setLoaded([...loaded, id])
};
```

Notice that arrays are immutable, so we create a new array with all the existing elements plus the new id and assign this new array to the state.

Your `CardList` takes the same props as before, but the mapped `Card` instances take the props a little differently, since they need to include the specific `id`:

```
<Card 
  load={() => load(i)}
  loadState={loadState.includes(i)}
  // rest of your props go here
  />
```

Comment: I've tried creating an array of state e.g const 
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState([false, false (till the 10th value]) but I'm facing issues updating the state in the onImageLoaded function

Comment: I have added some examples in the answer

Comment: Initially the loaded array was displaying only the last id, it seems it was overwritten with the new id value of the onImageLoaded function.
This seemed to fix it setLoaded(prevState => [...prevState, id]).
Other than that, this seems to work for me. Thanks a lot, I've spent a lot of time trying to get this to work

Comment: Ah, yes. That would be correct. What happens otherwise is that the 'onImageLoaded' function captures the value of loaded when the component is first rendered and not on updates. Another approach would be to use the 'useCallback' hook to update te 'onImageLoaded' function whenever 'loaded' changes